# const value and RVO

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have this function:

```
template <class A>
inline A f()
{
  A const r(/* a very complex and expensive construction */);

  return r;
}
```

Is it a good idea to declare `r` `const`, since a `const` variable cannot be moved? Note that the returned value is not `const`. The qualm I am grappling is, that `r` truly is `const`, but it may not be a good idea to declare it as such. Yet the qualifier should be helping the compiler generate better code.

Comment: `inline` is redundant above.

Comment: no it's not, we're dealing with a function template, not a member function.

Comment: @user1095108, Those are implicitly inline as well, and it's only functions defined inside a class body (even friend ones).

Comment: @user1095108 `template` functions have been implicitly `inline` since they where added to the language.  `inline` mostly means "colliding definitions from distinct compilation units will be silently discarded", which is sort of a requirement for most use of `template` functions.

Comment: @Yakk Are you sure? On my compiler, inline keyword changed the likelihood of template function being inlined or not.

Comment: @NeilKirk Not certain, and I could easily see compilers treating the word `inline` to give hints to inline a function.

Comment: `template` functions are not implicitly `inline`.  They do have the multiple-identical-definitions-allowed semantic, which is the only *required* behavior of the `inline` keyword, but they may not automatically have other implementation-specific behavior provided by `inline`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Exactly! This fine distinction is a cause for major debugging headaches. I wrote `inline` to give people the opportunity to comment, what happens if the function gets inlined and what happens when not inlined.

Comment: @user1095108 You didn't mention anything about inlining in your question. Whether a function is inlined should not effect its observable behavior.

Comment: And compilers are under no obligation to use `inline` to affect the likelihood of a function being inlined as an optimisation tactic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [demonstrated here](http://ideone.com/Pe8yRL), NRVO elides the copy of `r` implied by the line `return r;`

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  const char* name;
  A( const char* name_ ):name(name_) { std::cout << "created " << name << "\n"; }
  A(A const&){ std::cout << "copied " << name << "\n"; }
  A(A &&){ std::cout << "moved " << name << "\n"; }
};

A f() {
  std::cout << "start of f()\n";
  A const r("bob");
  std::cout << "body of f()\n";
  return r;
}

int main() {
  A x = f();
}
```

And the copy in `main` is also elided.

If you block NRVO and RVO in some other way (for instance using the flag `-fno-elide-constructors` when compiling with GCC), the `const` can cause your object to be copied instead of `move`d.  You can see this if we [remove the copy constructor from `A`](http://ideone.com/3g0jSK):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  const char* name;
  A( const char* name_ ):name(name_) { std::cout << "created " << name << "\n"; }
  //A(A const&){ std::cout << "copied " << name << "\n"; }
  A(A &&){ std::cout << "moved " << name << "\n"; }
};

A f() {
  std::cout << "start of f()\n";
  A const r("bob");
  std::cout << "body of f()\n";
  return r;
}

int main() {
  A x = f();
}
```

the code no longer compiles.  While the copy constructor isn't executed so long as NRVO occurs, its existence is required by your `const` local variable.

Now, NRVO requires a few things, such as a single variable which is returned along every single execution path of the function in question: if you ever "abort" and do a `return A()`, NRVO is blocked, and your `const` local variable suddenly forces a copy at all return sites.

Comment: So, I gather, a returned `const` is worse than a non-`const`? We pray for a `move` if NRVO is blocked.

Comment: It isn't actually necessary to have a *copy* constructor.  http://ideone.com/n867vx

Comment: @user1095108 no.  If NRVO occurs, no `const` and non-`const` are distinguished only by the requirement for which of a copy or move constructor must exist.  `const` means that the copy constructor must exist, and non-`const` means that either a move or copy constructor must exist.  If NRVO occurs, *neither* is called, regardless of the variable being `const` or non-`const`.  NRVO is not guaranteed by the standard, but every major compiler does it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, but the `const` move constructor is a bit of a dirty corner case.  I mean really, non-mutating move?  What will we have next, guaranteed compile time function evaluation without `template` metaprogramming?

Comment: @BenVoigt but you move a `const` `rvalue`, highly unusual. Still, very nice trick hehehehe.

Comment: @user1095108: It's not the most useful construct, but it shows that the distinction is between `const` and non-`const` parameter to the constructor, and not between copy and move constructor.

Comment: @Yakk I meant, from the perspective that a move is "cheaper"` than a copy.

Comment: @Yakk: You think `constexpr` is a dirty corner case too?

Comment: @BenVoigt not sure how `const&&` could be cheaper than `const&`?  And no, I was just making a joke about `constexpr`.

Comment: +1.  I know I'm not supposed to comment a +1 just for the heck of it.  But this +1 is from the lead author of move semantics in C++11.  I thought that might be worth a comment. :-)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont "_What will we have next, guaranteed compile time function evaluation without template metaprogramming?_" lololol, prescient :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `class A` is under your control, and you *want* to return `const` objects by move, you can do

```
mutable bool resources_were_stolen = false;
```

and set that to true in a `const` move constructor

```
A(const A&& other) { ...; other.resources_were_stolen = true; }
~A() { if (!resources_were_stolen) ... }
```

Actually, the destructor probably would become `if (resources_were_stolen) some_unique_ptr.release();`, using the fact that objects lose their `const`-ness during construction and destruction.

Comment: Would you say that returning a non-const is marginally better than returning a const? I know that a "move" is not necessarily "cheaper" than a "copy".